# Concluding from limiting behavior

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, geometric-probability

I've recently seen the following question on the internet:

> If I wanted to randomly find someone in an amusement park, would my odds of finding them be greater if I stood still or roamed around?

Which I formulate more precisely as follows:

> Take a closed euclidean space $S$ with billiard-ball mixing and ergodic dynamics of two point-like agents with uniformly random starting positions and directions (but with given velocities). Is the expected meeting time $E[\tau(v_1,v_2)]$, a function of the velocities of agent $1$ and agent $2$ respectively, a decreasing function of $v_2$ for any $v_1$?

Where the meeting time $\tau$ is defined as the minimum time $t>0$ for which the distance among agents $d(p_1,p_2)$ satisfies $d(p_1,p_2)<D$.

It seems like a fairly difficult thing to show or disprove, at least with my limited knowledge. However, the limiting behavior seems very simple:

$$E[\tau(v_1,\infty)] = 0$$

Which follows directly from the fact that the dynamics is ergodic and mixing (at infinite velocity the agent visits every point instantaneously). Also,

$$E[\tau(0,0)] = \infty$$

For sufficiently small $D$. There's also the fact that

$$E[\tau(v_1,v_2)] = E[\tau(v_2,v_1)]$$

Is there are way to conclude from those observations? Any solution is also welcome.

Comment: You're choosing $v_2$, but what is the assumed distribution for $v_1$? (It can't be "uniformly random" if there are arbitrarily large possible values).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah yes, $v_1$ is assumed fixed (that is, I ask the question for any $v_1$), I'll try to reformulate that, thanks.

Comment: Also, it looks questionable to say on the one hand that the two "agents" are point-like, and on the other hand that at infinite velocity one of them "visits every point instantaneously". At _any_ velocity, the set of all points ever visited will have measure zero -- in particular most points are _never_ visited, even in the limit of velocity going towards infinity.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Would it make sense if I rephrased as "almost every point" instead? It was my understanding that ergodicity implies visiting every point.

Comment: x @Real: It's not almost every point either. On the contrary _almost all points_ remain unvisited forever. I'm not familiar with the precise definition of "ergodic", but if it implies that all (or even almost all) points are eventually visited, then it's incompatible with assuming that the objects being described are pointlike.

Comment: @HenningMakholm From wikipedia: "term ergodic is used to describe a dynamical system which, broadly speaking, has the same behavior averaged over time as averaged over the space of all the system's states". Since I'm taking the starting conditions as uniformly distributed over the space, it is my understanding that for an ergodic system the average over time of the 'occupancy' of each region should also be uniform, that is, $E[1_T(x)] = <1_A(x)>$, where $<.>$ denotes average over time and $1_T(x)$ the indicator function which is valued $1$ is $x \in T$ and $0$ if $x \notin T$, for all set $T$.

Comment: x @Real: Yes, and in this case the measure of the set of visited points is uniformly $0$ at any time and for any starting point ... in other words, for any pair of velocities, if the starting points are chosen uniformly, the two agent will almost certainly _never meet_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Take the discrete system $x_p(t)=p+t \mod 2\pi, t \in \mathbb{N}$. The measure of the set of visited points is uniformly $0$ at any time and starting point $p$, but the measure of the limit as $t \to \infty $ is not $0$, right?

Comment: x @Real: Yes, for a fixed $p$, the set of all visited points $\{x_p(t)\mid t\in\mathbb N\}$ does have measure zero. (The set is countable, and every countable subset of $\mathbb R$ has measure zero). The set is _dense_ in $[0,2\pi]$, but dense sets can easily have measure zero.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah I see, thanks for the explanation. I'm not sure how to reformulate the problem statement then.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that the system of two balls is ergodic (which is true for strictly convex scatterers) and mixing fast (which nobody is able to prove by the moment but is also probably true), (very) roughly speaking you can think of it as of two independent (dicrete) random walks.

Do you know the answer for this simplified case of random walks? What about two independent Brownian motions?

If it works for random walks and Brownian motions then there is a chance that it works for billiard as well. But I am pretty sure it is way beyond the current technology of proofs for billiards.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not, I know mostly elemetary stochastic theory only. I would be quite satisfied with a proof for that case! I have a conviction that the answer should be simple for geometrical reasons though: for any closed and connected room the average minimum distance $\overline{D}_{min} = \iint D_{min}(p,p') \,dp\,dp'$ is of course a constant, so the expected minimum time $E[\tau_{min}(v_1,v_2)]$ must follow $E[\tau_{min}(v_1,\lambda_2v_2)] = \frac{1}{\lambda_2+c}E[\tau_{min}(v_1,v_2)] $ (by noting that $\tau_{min} = \frac{D_{min}-D}{v_1+v_2}$). Something analogous for the average case?

Comment: You should specify you system more explicitly. What is $D_{min}$? Why your formula for $\tau_min$ is true and why does it make sense at all? In particular what does it mean $\lambda_2 v_2$? If you play standard billiard, your $v_2$ is a pair made of a point and a tangent vector, the vector you can multiply by a constant, the point -- no.  Note also that if your billard flow is ergodic but not mixing (if you have a square billiard with no obstacles, for example), and you start two balls flowing in the same direction (and same speed), your $\tau_{min} = \infty$.

Comment: Ah ok I will add the requirement of being mixing, thanks. I was thinking in justifying the brownian motion already. $D_{min}$ is the minimum distance among two points. It's just an observation that if the agents were headed direcly toward eachother the anwer would be positive. The values $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the absolute values of the velocities (the direction would be chosen at random).

Comment: If there is a line connecting $p$ and $p'$, then $D_{min}$ is simply $d(p,p')$ (I didn't define due to lack of space). The statement of the problem requires showing $E[\tau(v_1,v_2)]$ is a decreasing function of $v_2$. By multiplying $v_2$ by a constant $\lambda_2$ the value $E[\tau_{min}(v_1,v_2)]$ strictly decreases as we would want for the random direction case.

Comment: If the billiard is mixing then the infimum (over time) of distances between two points starting with random directions is zero. Also I feel that I do not understand what do you mean by the symbol $E$. Is it an integral over time? Over all possible choices of the first speed (i.e. over $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$ )? Over direction of the first velocity (i.e. over $S^1$)? Over both coordinates?

Comment: It's (perhaps unclearly?) in the problem statement: "random starting positions and directions", so we take both directions ($S_1 \times S_1$ if I understand correctly) and both positions at random. The magnitudes of the velocities are deterministic, so that the expectation is a function of them. It comes out as a 4-tuple integral averaging the meeting time. I guess a more fitting terminology would be $E[\tau(p_1,p_2,\theta_1,\theta_2|v_1,v_2)]$, the expectation being taken over $p_1,p_2,\theta_1,\theta_2$.

Comment: The 1-D case seems fairly trivial, I will try to work it out completely for both billiards and brownian motion and report back.

Comment: Ok, but I still do not understand why your algebraic formulae relating $\tau_{min}$ and $D,v_1,v_2$ and expectations of $\tau_{min}$ for scaled $v_2$ are true. Note also that when the speeds of your particles are different the flow probably does not preserve the Lebesgue measure and the limiting SRB measure is singular.